# Android: change button background/text/compoundDrawables with selector XML

Tags: android, button

I have already been using selector drawables to make my button change background according to the state.

However, I also want to change the text color and left compound drawable together with the background. But the default selector XML atrribute does not contain any "android:textColor" or "android:drawableLeft" to be assigned.

I know I can always achieve this with extend my own button class, but is there any clean way out?

Comment: Try to create your own style for buttons http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very sure about drawables but for changing textcolor depending upon button state, I use selectors as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/color_light_green"></item>
    <item android:color="#fff"></item>
    //state you want
</selector>
```

and then apply it to textColor attribute in the xml as,

```
android:textColor="@drawable/selector_btn_text_color"
```

Eclipse doesn't auto suggest color attribute in selector but we can do it. :)

Comment: Thanks for you inspiration! I think I am a little trapped by my first thought. Now I have implemented three different selector xml for bg/textcolor/drawable, and assign each to the bg/textcolor/leftdrawable attribute. They all work like a charm!

Comment: Nice. Thanks for telling the drawable part I will also try to implement it by your way. :)